# «В обручальном кольце» или «с обручальным кольцом»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Как правильно  сказать:

> мужчина в обручальном кольце

или

> мужчина с обручальным кольцом?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В обручальном кольце - это как "в плаще"?

Думаю, это некорректно, я представляю себе огромное кольцо и в нём такого маленького мужчинку. Корректно "с обручальным кольцом".

Answer (score 2):

Мужчина не может быть в обручальном кольце, т.к. предлог ***в*** указывает на место, пространство, вместилище, среду, сферу деятельности и т.п. в пределах или внутри которых находится кто-, что-л., происходит что-л.

Answer (score 1):

Далеко не во всём, что можно на себя надеть, можно пребывать. Одно дело очки или погоны, другое - кольцо. Мужчина в кольце - это солдат взятой в кольцо армии.